# Couldn't load specified math lib(s) when using a script from CPAN

Tags: perl

I'm using perl SSH module from CPAN. After executing the script, I get this error

```
Math::BigInt: couldn't load specified math lib(s), 
fallback to Math::BigInt::Calc 
at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/Crypt/DH.pm line 6
```

This is the script:

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $host = 'mymachine.com';
my $user = 'xyz';
my $pass = 'xyx';

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
    $ssh->login($user, $pass);
    my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
```

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: Does the script above really start with '!' or did you leave out  the '#' that should precede it by accident?

Answer (score 1):

It probably means you are missing perl modules.

`Crypt::DH` wants either `Math::BigInt` or `Math::BigInt::GMP` or `Math::BigInt::Pari`. Try to install these and watch out for warnings.

(`cpan> install Math::BigInt`, `cpan> install Math::Pari`, `cpan> install Math::PMG`)

If you get a

```
WARNING! No GMP libraries were detected!
```

then you might be missing header files for [libgmp](http://gmplib.org/) (the development package for libgmp).

Comment: Or even better, rather than installing modules via CPAN, use the standard ubuntu packages.  This would have avoided the problem in the 1st place by automatically installing all the necessary prerequisites.  apt-get install libnet-ssh-perl libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl ...  etc.